# Return type of WinJS.xhr responseXML property

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, winjs

I'm  using WinJS to write a Windows Store app that needs to work with XML documents.

I quite easily found the WinJS.xhr function, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the value I get back from it.

Since I have to extract a lot of information from specific nodes, but don't have to do anything with the document as a whole, I'm calling with `responseType: "document"` and saving the `result.responseXML` property. However, I can't find anywhere in the documentation exactly what methods/members are safe to use off of this object (read: what type of object is it, exactly?).

The MSDN documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms534370.aspx states:

> **Using responseXML in Windows Store apps using JavaScript**
>
> In Windows Store apps using JavaScript, this property returns a
>   [`DOMParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff975060.aspx) object instead of an `IXMLDOMDocument` object.

but the linked documentation on `DOMParser` only lists one method, `parseFromString`, which is used to *make* DOM elements from a raw string representation. This makes no sense considering the XML should supposedly have already been made into a DOM format, per the definition of the "document" responseType.

I tried going ahead and treating it as if it were an `IXMLDOMDocument`, but I get a function not found error on calling `selectNodes`, so it really isn't that type, either.

In fact, examining the object in the debugger reveals it doesn't even possess the `parseFromString` method.

I'm hesitant to just look at the members in the debugger and guess at which ones do what I want. Several of them look pretty familiar from manipulating the HTML DOM, but I don't like making assumptions.

Can anyone here who might have a better understanding of the WinJS API enlighten me on just how I should be treating this object and what methods/members are/aren't safe to use?

**EDIT:** In order to continue what I was doing, I've managed to fudge my way along by using `querySelectorAll`, which does exist on that object and seems to do what it suggests. However, if only for the sake of anyone else trying to work with these things who might see this (beyond my own satisfaction), I'd still like a concrete answer to this little enigma.

Comment: in  the msdn documentation page it has the following example which uses `oReq.responseXML.xml` so try to retrieve the `.xml` property string from the `responseXML`

Comment: I tried that, actually. The property isn't there. Though that example isn't entire applicable: it doesn't specify a responseType and I do not believe "document" is default. The contents of `responseXML` can vary if you specify the resource type you're retrieving. It's also possible that the contents of `responseXML` vary between `WinJS.xhr` and a bare `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: Again, I could be clearer if Microsoft's documentation was a bit more detailed.

Comment: maybe you should change the `responseType` to `XML` instead of `document` and treat response as xml string and handle as needed

Comment: The issue with that is that I need to manipulate the XML as DOM. I need the ability to get specific nodes and add/remove them dynamically. I'd just have to parse it all, anyway. As it is, I have my code working. I can also confirm that the document and its elements don't have the same set of methods as the native HTML document/nodes, but they both do share `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`, and thankfully all the operations I need to do on the XML have paths simple enough that I can use CSS selectors instead of XPath, though I've had to use a couple tricks.

Comment: yes but then you can instantiate a `DomParser` yourself and call `parseFromString` with the `responseXML.xml` string and manipulate as needed